# Как сделать чтобы часть кода перешла в HTML без изменений?

Tags: jade, pug

Из:
`input(name="title", #newtitle)`
Получаем:
`input name="title" #newtitle="#newtitle"`

Как сделать на выходе: 
`input name="title" #newtitle`

???

Comment: Вообще в jade использавние # означает id элемента и ставиться input#idElement что будет равно input id="idElement"

Comment: Мне не нужно  ` id="element"  ` , нужно ` #Element `. В данном контексте это не id, это "ссылка".

Comment: так нельзя делать в HTML используйте data-elemet="" и все равно будет data-elemet="data-elemet" т.к. это стандарт атрибут не может быть без данных. ну максимум пустой.

Comment: У меня это отлично работает в HTML. Только не понятно как из jade в html вывести. Разве нет возможности просто перенести текст как есть без трансформации?

Comment: Зачем вы ломаете стандарты, вы не правильно пишите код HTML, так код писать нельзя, что не понятного? нельзя использовать в теге #element как атрибут, т.к. когда вы будите использовать этот атрибут в jQuery то єто будет понимать как ID элемента!!!!

Comment: Во-первых: если он будет понимать как id, то пусть так и понимает, мне это никак не мешает. 
Во-вторых: Я не планирую использовать jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите вот так:

```
input(name='title', #newtitle='')
```